# An instance of Eisenstein's criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am trying to prove the following assertion:

Given a prime number $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ , let $$f =\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}{a_ix^i}\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$$
which is a polynomial of odd degree. Furthermore, we assume $p\nmid a_{2n+1}, p^2\mid a_{0}, \ldots, a_n, p\mid a_{n+1}, \ldots, a_{2n}$ and $p^3\nmid a_0$.

The aim is to prove $f$ is irreducible. Obviously, the Eisenstien Criterion cannot be used rightaway.  What I tried was to make a linear change of variables. But it did not simplify matters. Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of linear change of variables did you try?

Comment: @Phira, such as $x+1$

Comment: @Phira, so if it is sure that it works, I will try again. It was long. That's why I did not post it. But will it work?

Comment: While you should ask yourself also where exactly the substitution does not work, I think the best way to solve this problem is to adapt the proof of Eisenstein's criterion. *Where* does it break down?

Comment: BTW, I didn't ask you "Why does it not work?" to insinuate that you made a calculating error.

Comment: @Phira, the usual proof breaks down where $P^2\mid a_0$ but $p^3\nmid a_0$. This will not help to proceed. I appreciate your help. So, what's the hint?

Comment: No, you just cite the hypothesis, but not the place in the proof of the criterion where it is used. The proof method of Eisenstein's criterion does work for your problem.

Comment: I think it is the hypothesis that $P^2\mid a_0$. Okay, thanks. I will try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a decomposition of $f=P\cdot Q$ with $P(X)=b_k X^k+\ldots+b_0,Q(X)=c_m X^m+\ldots c_0\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and since the degrees add up to $2n+1$ we suppose without loss of generality that $m=\text{deg}(Q)\leq n<\text{deg}(P)$.

1. Step: Reduce mod $p$ to show that $P$ and $Q$ must be Eisenstein polynomials in $p$.
2. Step: Derive a contradiction from the fact that $p^2|a_m=c_m b_0+\ldots+c_0 b_m$ by showing that $p^2$ divides all the summands except $c_m b_0$.

Comment: Michalis, thank you very much.

Comment: @Chulumba: No problem. You might not know, but it makes this page more organised if you mark correct answers by ticking the symbol under the vote buttons.

Comment: Michalis, done.